# How to fix two flip-bit errors in a 3 qubit input

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, error-correction

Aware of how a 1-bit flip can be fixed for 3-qubit input by having 2 Ancilla bits, encoding, and using the Toffoli gate to fix the error and decode. How can this idea be extended for a 2-bit flip (either 2 of the 3 qubit-inputs) and what does the circuit look like?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this? Have you tried any approaches to construct such a code?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out now via taking 3 ancilla qubits instead of 2 and figuring out the invariant in case 2 bits are flipped.

Comment: Please add the circuit, if possible, and the approach you have taken so that this post will be helpful to others in the future.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).